# Como colocar duas palavras na mesma linha?

Tags: vim

**Bom dia, comunidade!**

Estou estudando o vim.
Gostaria de colocar duas palavras (de direita para esquerda e da esquerda para direita) na mesma linha no vim.
Por exemplo:

```
def br(esq, dir):
```

gostaria de colocar com uma tecla para

```
def br(dir, esq):
```

Para colocar da direita para esquerda fiz

```
nnoremap <C-Left> B"zdwBh"zpi<Esc>w
```

Mais isso não funciona bem com vírgulas.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso. A maioria vai depender de especificidades do seu texto, como por exemplo onde o cursor está, ou se são apenas dois parâmetros sempre, etc.

Deixo aqui uma forma relativamente simples de entender que faz o que deseja:

Dado o texto, e a posição do cursor especificados:

```
def br(esq,| dir):
            \_ Cursor esteja aqui
```

Pressione:

- `dt)` que irá deletar todo o conteúdo até o caracter `)`
- `T(` que irá mover o cursor para o caracter `(`
- `vt,p` que irá entrar no modo visual, selecionar até o caracter `,`, e colar o conteúdo deletado anteriormente
- `t)p` que irá mover o cursor para o caracter `)` e colar o que foi removido no comando anterior.

Com essa sequência de comandos você pode fazer um re-map e colocar no seu arquivo .vimrc ou gravar em uma macro, por exemplo.

Novamente, existem outros caminhos que você pode seguir que podem se adequar melhor ao seu dia a dia. Se você achar melhor, pode procurar plugins que façam o especificado também. Provavelmente eles vão fazer melhor e de forma mais genérica do que o exemplo que eu dei.

Para opções mais genéricas de resposta, e algumas sugestões de plugins, veja [esta resposta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/610) (em inglês).